# How to change sample rate for all files in a directory

Tags: bash, shell, sox

How do I change the sample rate for every file in the folder?

I have the following code and it just erases the files -- the file size becomes 0.

```
for i in wav/*.wav; do
    sox -r 8000 -e unsigned -b 16 -c 1 "$i" "$i"
done
```

Why is that?

Comment: How do you change sample rate for one file?

Answer (score 1):

You're telling sox to write to the same file it's reading from. So when sox goes to prep the output file, it opens it for reading and clears it. But since that's also the input file, the input file has now been cleared, and sox has nothing to read.

Instead, you should use a temporary file one way or another. Here's one way:

```
for i in wav/*.wav; do
    if sox -r 8000 -e unsigned -b 16 -c 1 "$i" "$i.resampled"; then
        # This way we will only replace the original file with the 
        # resampled version if sox returns a zero (no error) error code.
        mv "$i.resampled" "$i"
    else
        soxerrno = $?
        echo "Sox reported error number $soxerrno while processing file $i"
    fi
done
```

NB: I don't use sox, so I didn't double-check the rest of your sox options, just the *infile* and *outfile* arguments.